# free iOS apps that allow end users to purchase merchant products?

Tags: app-store, in-app-purchase

Anyone knows the policies for free iOS apps that allow end users to purchase merchant products?

For example, Walmart iOS appl that has a shopping card and allows their customers to purchase things using the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its digital then you must offer it via an in-app purchase (and give apple 30%).

It's it's a physical product then you can do that (look at Amazon/Tesco/Argos apps).